# Memory problem ResourceExhaustedError OOM when allocating tensor in a CNN model - how to decrease number parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, image, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

my binary classification model has images which I resized to 224x224 resolution. My basic CNN model is defined as follows:

```
input_shape
(224, 224, 3)

cnn_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   Conv2D(32, (5,5), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', input_shape =(input_shape)),
   Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', input_shape =(input_shape)),
   MaxPooling2D(2,2),
   Flatten(),
   Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
   Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"),                       

])

cnn_model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 224, 224, 32)      2432      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 128)     36992     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 112, 112, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1605632)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               205521024 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 205,560,577
Trainable params: 205,560,577
Non-trainable params: 0
```

It gives me an out of memory error, (ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1605632,128] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc) when I try to train the model.

so I can see there are 1605632 parameters in the Flatten() layer.

how can I change my architecture to reduce the number of these parameters?
I do not want to change the resolution because I will also be using visual transformer pretrained models, which will require the 224 x 224 resolution.

thank you!

Comment: It looks like not a huge model. What about your `batch size`? Reduce your batch size is the easist way.

Comment: yes I have reduced it to 8, still the same error.

Comment: Then the inner conv2d's filter size `128->64`

Comment: Your `max_pooling` output is massive. Do you need it that big? Can't you add a few `conv`/`max_pool` layers to bring it to something like `32x32` (or `16x16`)? You can see that your subsequent dense layer got 205 million parameters.